# How to make AWS EFS work fast? (looks like a bug)

Tags: performance, filesystems, amazon-web-services, nfs, throughput

I am copying (by DataSync) from one EFS to another EFS (both Provisioned (1024 MiB/s)) at 14.57 MiB/s. Both systems are in the same subnet in the US. (Moreover, when I tried to change them back to Bursting to avoid paying for non-existing Provisioned service, it refused saying that I reached a limit for number of changes.)

Why is it so slow? Is there any way to make EFS fast? Or do I need to go for EBS is I need fast storage? Any other alternatives (except of EFS and EBS) on AWS? (I know about S3, but isn't it even slower than EFS?)

Note that I changed to Provisioned from Bursting during copying.

Comment: Sounds like you should be contacting Amazon (AWS) support.  Your transfer mode more than likely cannot be changed dynamically for transfers in progress but Amazon support can confirm that fact

Comment: What is the size of the files? How many files? There is likely to be overhead setting up connections so smaller files will be slower and larger files faster.

Comment: I don't know the exact statistics but I have already taken the decision to use FSx instead of EFS. So, it is no more relevant.